# SQLite3::SQLException: no such column:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [undefined method `to_f' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x472d0a0>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12845647/undefined-method-to-f-for-activerecordrelation0x472d0a0)

I'm trying to make a call tracking application to learn twilio and rails.

Right now, I would like to make a graph that shows a user how many phone calls a particular phone number gets per day.

The schema is user has_many phones has_many calls.

I try to make the graph by creating an instance method that counts the number of phones on a particular day, but when I try executing the code, I get the error :

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: calls.placed_at: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "calls"  WHERE "calls"."phone_id" = 44 AND ("calls"."placed_at" BETWEEN '2012-09-15 00:00:00.000000' AND '2012-09-15 23:59:59.999999')
```

I don't quite understand the code I'm using for the instance method, and it's probably calling the wrong column. Your help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the important part of my call model:

```
def total_on(date)
  calls.where(placed_at: date.beginning_of_day..date.end_of_day).count
end
```

Here's how I'm counting the phone calls in my show view

```
<%= (1.month.ago.to_date..Date.today).map { |date| @phone.total_on(date).to_f}.inspect %>
```

Here's how I define the @phone variable

```
@phone = Phone.find_by_id(params[:id])
```

Here's my complete phone model (for schema reference)

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: phones
#
#  id              :integer          not null, primary key
#  name            :string(255)
#  twilio_number   :integer
#  original_number :integer
#  user_id         :integer
#  created_at      :datetime         not null
#  updated_at      :datetime         not null
#

class Phone < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :original_number, :user_id, :name, :twilio_number
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :calls, dependent: :destroy

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :twilio_number, presence: true
  validates :original_number, presence: true
  validates :user_id, presence: true

  default_scope order: 'phones.created_at DESC'

  validate :check_phone_limit, :on => :create

  def check_phone_limit
    if User.find(self.user_id).at_max_phone_limit?
      self.errors[:base] << "Cannot add any more phones"
    end
  end

  def original_number=(value)
    num = value.to_s.gsub(/[^0-9+]/, "")
    write_attribute(:original_number, num.to_i)
  end

def total_on(date)
  calls.where(placed_at: date.beginning_of_day..date.end_of_day).count
end

end
```

Here's my complete call model

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: calls
#
#  id               :integer          not null, primary key
#  AccountSid       :string(255)
#  From             :string(255)
#  To               :string(255)
#  CallStatus       :string(255)
#  ApiVersion       :string(255)
#  Direction        :string(255)
#  FromCity         :string(255)
#  FromState        :string(255)
#  FromZip          :string(255)
#  FromCountry      :string(255)
#  ToCity           :string(255)
#  ToState          :string(255)
#  ToZip            :string(255)
#  ToCountry        :string(255)
#  CallSid          :string(255)
#  DialCallSid      :string(255)
#  DialCallDuration :string(255)
#  DialCallStatus   :string(255)
#  RecordingUrl     :string(255)
#  phone_id         :integer
#  DialCallMinutes  :integer
#  created_at       :datetime
#  updated_at       :datetime
#

class Call < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :AccountSid, :From, :To, :CallStatus, :ApiVersion, :Direction, :FromCity, :FromState, :FromZip, :FromCountry, :ToCity, :ToState, :ToZip, :ToCountry, :CallSid, :DialCallSid, :DialCallDuration, :DialCallStatus, :RecordingUrl, :DialCallMinutes
  belongs_to :phone


  def self.create_from_incoming_call(params)

   user_phone = Phone.find_by_twilio_number(params['To']) #Finds the phone number in the database based on what phone Twilio is calling


    twilio_request_params = {
      :CallSid => params['CallSid'],
      :AccountSid => params['AccountSid'],
      :From => params['From'],
      :To => params['To'],
      :CallStatus => params['CallStatus'],
      :ApiVersion => params['ApiVersion'],
      :Direction => params['Direction'],
        :FromCity => params['FromCity'],
        :FromState => params['FromState'],
      :FromZip => params['FromZip'],
      :FromCountry => params['FromCountry'],
      :ToCity => params['ToCity'],
      :ToState => params['ToState'],
      :ToZip => params['ToZip'],
      :ToCountry => params['ToCountry']
      :phone_id => user_phone.phone_id

    }


    call = Call.new(twilio_request_params)
    call.save  
    return call

  end

  def Call.update_dial_call(params)

    twilio_request_params = {
        :DialCallSid => params['DialCallSid'],
        :DialCallDuration => params['DialCallDuration'],
        :DialCallStatus => params['DialCallStatus'],
        :RecordingUrl => params['RecordingUrl'],
      :DialCallMinutes => (params['DialCallDuration'].to_f/60.to_f).ceil
    }

    call = Call.where( :CallSid => params['CallSid'] ).first
    call.update_attributes twilio_request_params
    call.save

  end


end
```

I've been stuck on this for a while; any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: i don't see placed_at column in your call table, Are you sure you dn't mean created_at ?

Comment: ...wow. Doon, thank you. Please place that as an answer, and I'll embarrassingly accept :P.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your call model uses the standard rails created_at, yet your query was using placed_at, which doesn't exist.